# Counter measure if/when external CSS file is not loaded when the page did

Tags: css, stylesheet

Due to network or some other reasons, some sites do not have their css files loaded and you will see unformatted/un-layout-ed ugly page.

It happened to pages I did before also. Kind of beyond control from a developer/design point of view.

I'm thinking of something like this place at the top of the page and obvious:

```
/*.... header and stuff */

<body>
<h2 id="hiddennote">If you do not see this page properly, please refresh</h2>
/*.... rest of the page .... */
```

The external stylesheet have a definition like this:

```
/* other styles defined */

#hiddennote {display: none;}
```

Functionally I know it'll work. Any drawbacks?

Comment: The obvious drawback is if the page fails to load the CSS the second time.

Comment: Ha, I really didn't think about that. Why don't you put it in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another potential drawback is that it depends on the user knowing what the page is supposed to look like. You could fix that by changing the language of the message to something like, "This page is not displaying properly! While you are free to use the content below, you may want to refresh your browser to try loading the layout and styling information." You could also include a screenshot, assuming your images are not hosted on the same troublesome network.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious drawback is if the page fails to load the CSS the second time.